# How to add multiple values to same field in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add multiple image Uri's to the same field in Firestore.

[image: Screenshot of my firestore db].

I have been trying several methods, instead of adding image Uris to the same field it creates multiple documents in fire store. I need help.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROUND:" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imgUri = imageUris.get(i);
        imageFilesPath = storageReference.child("Ads_images" + "/" + "Ad_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

        imageFilesPath.putFile(imgUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful() && task != null) {

                    LIST.add(task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    Log.e(TAG, "List inside"+LIST.size());

                    Map<String, Object> adMap = new HashMap<>();
                    adMap.put("user_id", user_id);
                    adMap.put("description", "Small description is shown here");
                    adMap.put("imageUris", Arrays.asList(LIST.get(0)));
                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Ads").add(adMap);
                }else {

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, can you please share your source code for this, i need to create a react and can't get how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `add()` on a collection, Firestore creates a new document. Since you now call `add()` after uploading each file, you get a separate document for each file. If you want to add your URL to an existing document, you must get a `DocumentReference` to that document and update it.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Ads").doc("v1ys3tyQ7vhHLD0ietAw").update(adMap);
```

To add a URL to the `imageUris` array, you will need to first load the current contents of that array (to determine what index to add the item to). This read-to-update sequence is somewhat inefficient at scale. If that matters to your app, you might want to consider [storing the URLs in a map inside the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) instead, or [storing them in a subcollection under the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections).

Comment: Thank you It worked well after I stored URLs in a map and used the "update" method instead of set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<String,Object> imageUrl = new HashMap<>();
 imageUrl.put("ImageUrl", imageList);
```

```
    firebaseFirestore.collection("ImageDetails").document(userId)
                                                .set(imageUrl,SetOptions.merge());
```

this worked fine for me too, but i passed the list separately once all the list items were added,here `imageUrl` is my map object and `imageList` is an arraylist for storing generated image uri download links.

Also by any chance could I get the look at the code at how you fetched back all those image uri